# jQuery: Any better way to write this? Muliple calls to the same function with parameters

Tags: jquery

```
function bookingResults(){
  checkAllRadios("#acknowledgeAll", ".acknowledgeThis");
  checkAllRadios("#confirmAll", ".confirmThis");
  checkAllRadios("#rejectAll", ".rejectThis");
}
```

When the id is clicked, check all the elements with the class name.

Comment: Seems wasteful for jQuery to re-implement functions when there's already a native way to do that.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc each browser may have a different native way... jQuery normalizes the behavior.

Comment: be sure to check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript/5407529#5407529

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how your function works. But you can do:

```
$('.acknowledgeThis, .confirmThis, .rejectThis').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding $('.acknowledgeThis, .confirmThis, .rejectThis').attr('checked', 'checked'); , that's the old way to do it in jQuery.  But if you're using any version 1.6 or higher, the correct way to do it now is this:

$('.acknowledgeThis, .confirmThis, .rejectThis').prop('checked', true);

The attr() setter version has been deprecated since 1.6, and might be removed in a future version.